# Toastbar message alignment with icon

Tags: codenameone

I'm using following code to display error messages:

ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Can't start an activity when another activity is running", 4000);

How could I make the icon aligned with the text properly. Please refer the screenshots.

[image][image]

Comment: Did you style toastbar or any other related UIID's?

Comment: @Shai I haven't add any style/UIID for toast bar.

Comment: Anything else in the theme that might be impacted? Try adding a LONG timeout to the toastbar then use Component inspector to inspect the UIID's in the hierarchy to see where the padding comes from